# Using pandas' TimeGrouper() to find column counts by intervals of 1 second

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the dataframe "data" indexed by Timestamp as follow:

```
Index                                Receiver     Type         Retry
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000         R1          Data         1
1970-01-01 00:00:00.800000000         R1          Non-Data     1
1970-01-01 00:00:01.000287000         R2          Data         0
1970-01-01 00:00:01.600896000         R2          Data         1
1970-01-01 00:00:02.001388000         R1          Data         1
1970-01-01 00:00:02.004698000         R1          Non-Data     1
1970-01-01 00:00:02.006706000         R2          Data         1
1970-01-01 00:00:02.501351000         R2          Data         1
1970-01-01 00:00:02.810382000         R1          Data         0
1970-01-01 00:00:03.001981000         R1          Data         0
1970-01-01 00:00:03.377116000         R1          Data         0
1970-01-01 00:00:03.701811000         R2          Data         1
1970-01-01 00:00:03.910326000         R2          Data         0
1970-01-01 00:00:03.951355000         R2          Non-Data     1
```

I want to find all rows where Type is "Data" and Retry equals 1 and then group the index in intervals of 1 second to find counts for each Receiver type.

**Desired Output as df2:**

```
Index                        R1   R2
1970-01-01 00:00:00          1    0
1970-01-01 00:00:01          0    1
1970-01-01 00:00:02          1    2
1970-01-01 00:00:03          0    1
```

Comment: And whats the expected output for the given data?

Comment: as @Bharath asks, it would be much easier to understand if you could show desired output. It may also help to make the example data slightly larger (10 lines or so?) It's fine to show coldspeed's code but we don't really need that as we can see it below and I don't really understand what is wrong about coldspeed's code anyway -- but simply showing desired results would probably make that obvious.

Comment: @Muhammad Asif Khan I will go with your last sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with a simple `pivot_table` i.e

```
ndf = df[df['Type'].eq('Data')].pivot_table(columns=['Receiver'],values='Retry',
             index=pd.Grouper(key='Index',freq='s'), aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)

Receiver             R1  R2
Index                      
1970-01-01 00:00:00   1   0
1970-01-01 00:00:01   0   1
1970-01-01 00:00:02   1   2
1970-01-01 00:00:03   0   1
```

Comment: My answer is correct, but I'm giving you the bounty because I have to give it to someone. And besides, pivot_table is a nice touch.

Comment: Haha makes sense. Would have been easy if the question was like the one now before. And I saw the update now : )

Comment: Thank you everyone, and apologies for all the inconvenience caused before!

Answer (score 4):

> I originally set the bounty since I couldn't find the time to help OP,
>   but I was able to find some time and provide 4 options, all of which
>   address OP's question. I've also cleaned up the question to remove
>   redundant/stale information and prevent confusion.

**Option 1**
Use `query`/`eval`/*boolean indexing*, filter rows, and then use `get_dummies` + `resample` to get your output -

```
df = df.query("Type == 'Data' and Retry == 1")\
      .set_index('Index').Receiver.str.get_dummies().resample('1S').sum()

df

                     R1  R2
Index                      
1970-01-01 00:00:00   1   0
1970-01-01 00:00:01   0   1
1970-01-01 00:00:02   1   2
1970-01-01 00:00:03   0   1
```

Similar solution using `get_dummies` + `groupby` -

```
df = df.query("Type == 'Data' and Retry == 1").set_index("Index")\
         .Receiver.str.get_dummies().groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='s')).sum()

df
                     R1  R2
Index                      
1970-01-01 00:00:00   1   0
1970-01-01 00:00:01   0   1
1970-01-01 00:00:02   1   2
1970-01-01 00:00:03   0   1
```

In fact, `resample` and `groupby` + `pd.Grouper` are pretty much interchangeable operations.

---

**Option 2**
`crosstab` + `resample` -

```
i = df.query("Type == 'Data' and Retry == 1").set_index('Index').Receiver

df = pd.crosstab(i.index, i.values).resample('1S').sum()
df.index.name = df.columns.name = None

df
                     R1  R2                     
1970-01-01 00:00:00   1   0
1970-01-01 00:00:01   0   1
1970-01-01 00:00:02   1   2
1970-01-01 00:00:03   0   1
```

---

**Option 3**
`groupby` + `unstack` (I presume this to be the slowest one) -

```
df = df.query("Type == 'Data' and Retry == 1")\
       .set_index('Index')\
       .groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1S'), 'Receiver'])\
       .Receiver.count()\
       .unstack()\
       .fillna(0)

df

Receiver              R1   R2
Index                        
1970-01-01 00:00:00  1.0  0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:01  0.0  1.0
1970-01-01 00:00:02  1.0  2.0
1970-01-01 00:00:03  0.0  1.0
```

---

**Option 4**

`unstack` + `resample` -

```
df = df.query("Type == 'Data' and Retry == 1")\
       .set_index(['Index', 'Receiver'])\
       .assign(foo=1)\
       .foo.unstack(-1)\
       .resample('s')\
       .sum()\
       .fillna(0)

df

Receiver              R1   R2
Index                        
1970-01-01 00:00:00  1.0  0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:01  0.0  1.0
1970-01-01 00:00:02  1.0  2.0
1970-01-01 00:00:03  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Hi @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, In the same above solution (second approach), based on the two conditions, If I want to return "01" if column "Retry" contain only "0", return "10", if "Retry contain" only "1" and "11", if "Retry" contain both "0" and "1". All calculations should be done for "1S" frequency as specified. ...........  Thank you, [Asif]

Comment: Please be noted, I tried the second approach using "mask", but it gives wrong counts. The first approach is fine. I verified it by applying filters in MS Excel.

Comment: Dear @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, In the above solution using the second approach using "mask", gives wrong counts when applied on my original large df. I verified the results using filters in MS Excel. The first approach provides correct counts but as you said it "completely removes rows which do not satisfy your condition" which is not desired in y case. Can you please look at the second approach if there is something missing.

Comment: @MuhammadAsifKhan I don’t have the time to help you, so I placed a bounty on your question. Good luck.

Comment: :)  Bounty... Wow. Thank you...  I did not know about these features of stack-overflow. Its such an interesting platform.

Comment: @MuhammadAsifKhan I found some free time and wrote my own solution for you. There are 3 options, and you'll find that all of them work well. I have also cleaned up your question, because it was becoming unruly with multiple conflicting edits. Feel free to roll back if it is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1 -- masking + resample**

```
for r in ['R1','R2']:
    df['new'+r] = ((df.Type=='Data')&(df.Retry==1)&(df.Receiver==r)).astype(int)

df[['newR1','newR2']].resample('s').sum()
```

**Approach 2 -- unstacking + resample**

```
df=df[df.Type=='Data'].set_index('Receiver',append=True)
df['Retry'].unstack().resample('s').sum().fillna(0)
```

Results with either approach are essentially the same, with some minor formatting differences (this is the output from Approach 1):

```
                     newR1  newR2
Index                            
1970-01-01 00:00:00      1      0
1970-01-01 00:00:01      0      1
1970-01-01 00:00:02      1      2
1970-01-01 00:00:03      0      1
```

Quick discussion of different methods:  In many cases, both `unstack` and `pivot_table` can be used to accomplish similar tasks, as in this case.  But `pivot_table` (as in @Dark's answer) seems clearly superior in this case (but I'll leave my `unstack` answer here solely for comparison purposes).

Comment: Dear @JohnE, I have edited my question so that you can easily understand. Please look at the Edit above!

Comment: Dear @JohnE, please consider above the last edit. The data with desired output is given. Both input and output are data-frames.

Comment: As you can see, I am just counting the num of rows where Retry==1 and Type=="Data" for each receiver (R1 and R2)...

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm not missing anything in the OP's question. I focused on the very last example data, given under "Last Edit". Using that data, the below code yields the desired output.

Code:

```
data = '' # <the OP's dataframe here>

def my_grouper(df):
    df = df[df['Type'] == 'Data']
    return df.groupby(['Receiver'])['Retry'].sum()


grouped_data = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1S')).apply(my_grouper)
grouped_data = pd.DataFrame(grouped_data).unstack(1).fillna(0)
grouped_data.columns = grouped_data.columns.droplevel(0)
print(grouped_data)
```

Output:

```
Receiver             R1  R2
Index                      
1970-01-01 00:00:00   1   0
1970-01-01 00:00:01   0   1
1970-01-01 00:00:02   1   2
1970-01-01 00:00:03   0   1
```