# Pandas Time grouping columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df as below:

```
Index                                Receiver     Length         Retry
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000         R1          10             0
1970-01-01 00:00:00.800000000         R1          10             1
1970-01-01 00:00:01.000287000         R2          10             0
1970-01-01 00:00:01.600896000         R2          10             0
1970-01-01 00:00:02.001388000         R1          10             1
1970-01-01 00:00:02.004698000         R1          10             1
1970-01-01 00:00:02.006706000         R2          10             0
1970-01-01 00:00:02.501351000         R2          10             0
1970-01-01 00:00:02.810382000         R1          10             0
1970-01-01 00:00:03.001981000         R1          10             1
1970-01-01 00:00:03.377116000         R1          10             1
1970-01-01 00:00:03.701811000         R2          10             1
1970-01-01 00:00:03.910326000         R2          10             0
1970-01-01 00:00:03.951355000         R2          10             1
```

I need to group the df by time (1S), and then in each group, add the Length column values if Retry==1 for each R1 and R2.

I used below code, but it seems it ignore rows when there is no Retry=1 for R1 and R2 (i.e. condition is not met).

```
df2 = df.query("Retry == 1").groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1S'), 'Receiver']).Length.sum().unstack().fillna(0)
```

Desired Output is:

```
Index                        R1    R2
1970-01-01 00:00:00          10    0
1970-01-01 00:00:01          0     0
1970-01-01 00:00:02          20    0
1970-01-01 00:00:03          20    20
```

Similar problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406062/using-pandas-timegrouper-to-find-column-counts-by-intervals-of-1-second/47406188?noredirect=1#comment82244728_47406188).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing `datetime`s:

```
df2 = df2.reindex(pd.date_range(df2.index[0], df2.index[-1], freq='1S'), fill_value=0)
print (df2)
Receiver               R1    R2
1970-01-01 00:00:00  10.0   0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:01   0.0   0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:02  20.0   0.0
1970-01-01 00:00:03  20.0  20.0
```

Comment: It gives error as 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df2' referenced before assignment'

Comment: add my solutionion after your `df2 = df.query("Retry == 1").groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1S'), 'Receiver']).Length.sum().unstack().fillna(0)`

Comment: Yeah, thats what I did. These two lines are inside a function. When I called the function, it gives this error at your posted line. If I run both lines outside the function, it works fine. any clue?

Comment: Can you see your function?

Comment: Yeah, right, I am trying to figure it out.. I;ll get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Ooooops, everything was fine. Nothing wrong with the solution and neither with the function. It was spyder issue, when I restarted kernel, it perfectly worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would first pivot the data with [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) and group the data afterward:

```
df['Value'] = df['Length']*df['Retry']
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=df.index, columns='Receiver', values='Value')
df2 = df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1S')]).sum()
```